# When do I create an index for FTS?

Tags: mongodb

I am working on implementing a FTS in my website using node and mongoDB through mongoose.

I was wondering when do I need to create my indices?

1. Only the first time I ran the app?
2. Every time a document is added / modified?
3. periodically?

This is for some reason very unclear to me.

Thank you all!

Comment: you need to create index only once. From that moment on, it'll be maintained by the database.

Comment: Thank you! so... in my app.js I should create the index. Should I verify it doesn't already exist before creating it? (in case the app is restarted)

Comment: No, creating an index that already exists results in a no op, however, putting this in he application code may result in undesirable behaviour, especially when it comes to administrating the database and it's indexes

Comment: Don't know how it's done in mongoose world, but I imagine that you should create the indexes outside of app lifecycle. On deploy, perhaps

Comment: Ok!! This makes a lot of sense! Thank you both very much!